# Let $m=pq$ ($p$,$q$ distinct primes). Show that $x^{m-1} = 1 \pmod{m}$ has precisely $\gcd((p-1),(q-1))^2$ solutions

Tags: number-theory

Started with the fact that there exists a primitive root mod $m$, called '$a$' such that $x = a^i$. Then split the equation into modulo $p$ and modulo $q$ so that: $a^{i(m-1)} = 1 \pmod{p}$ and $1 \pmod{q}$. From there we have $i(m-1) = 1 \pmod{p-1}$ and $1 \pmod{q-1}$. Stuck here.

Comment: You should simplify $x^{pq}$ modulo $p$ and $q$.

Comment: There is no primitive root modulo $m$ (unless one of $p,q$ is $2$.)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$x^{m-1}\equiv x^{q-1}\pmod{p}\\x^{m-1}\equiv x^{p-1}\pmod{q}$$

You thus need $$x^{q-1}\equiv 1\pmod p\\x^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{q}$$

Now, given any $n$, show that there are $\gcd(n,p-1)$ solutions to:

$$x^{n}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$$

Then apply Chinese remainder theorem.

Answer (score 0):

By the Chinese remainder theorem, the number of solutions is $N_pN_q$
where $N_p$ is the number of solutions modulo $p$. Now modulo $p$
the congruence is
$$x^{pq-1}\equiv1\pmod p$$
and this is equivalent to
$$x^{q-1}\equiv1\pmod p$$
by Fermat's little theorem. How many solutions does a congruence $x^k\equiv1\pmod p$ have?